# IndexError Machine-Learning Python

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to do a ML algorithm on a netflix movies data set. One movie from the data set looks like this (it's csv):

Atrributes:

- show_id, type, title, director, cast, country, date_added,
  release_year, rating, duration, listed_in, description
  Movie example:
- s1,Movie,Dick Johnson Is Dead,Kirsten Johnson,,United
  States,"September 25, 2021",2020,PG-13,90 min,Documentaries,"As her
  father nears the end of his life, filmmaker Kirsten Johnson stages
  his death in inventive and comical ways to help them both face the
  inevitable."

Here is my code by now:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import difflib
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

#data collection + pre-processing
movies_data = pd.read_csv('netflix_titles.csv')

# printing the first 5 rows of the dataframe
#print(movies_data.head());
#print(movies_data.shape);


# selecting the relevant features for recommendation

selected_features = ['type','title','description','cast','director']
#print(selected_features);

# replacing the null valuess with null string

for feature in selected_features:
  movies_data[feature] = movies_data[feature].fillna('');

# combining all the 5 selected features

combined_features = movies_data['type']+' '+movies_data['title']+' '+movies_data['description']+' '+movies_data['cast']+' '+movies_data['director']
#print(combined_features)

# converting the text data to feature vectors
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
#
feature_vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(combined_features)
#
#print(feature_vectors);
#
# # getting the similarity scores using cosine similarity
#
similarity = cosine_similarity(feature_vectors)
#print(similarity.shape);
#
# # getting the movie name from the user
#
movie_name = input(' Enter your favourite movie name : ')
#
# # creating a list with all the movie names given in the dataset
#
list_of_all_titles = movies_data['title'].tolist()
#print(list_of_all_titles)
#
# # finding the close match for the movie name given by the user
#
find_close_match = difflib.get_close_matches(movie_name, list_of_all_titles)
#print(find_close_match)
#
close_match = find_close_match[0]
#print(close_match)
#
# # finding the index of the movie with title
#
index_of_the_movie = movies_data[movies_data.title == close_match]['show_id'].values[0]
index_replace=index_of_the_movie.replace('s', '');
index_integer=type(int(index_replace));
print(index_integer);
#
# # getting a list of similar movies
#
similarity_score = list(enumerate(similarity[index_integer]))
print(similarity_score)
```

and I am getting this exact error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/andre/PycharmProjects/MLProject/main.py", line 68, in <module>
    similarity_score = list(enumerate(similarity[index_integer]))
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Any ideas on how can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Well the variable index_integer is set to the type object integer. It is the class itself, not some value.
You have to change index_integer to something else. Because I don't know exactly what you were trying to do I can only guess. But removing the type() call should solve the problem.

Comment: is there any way to make the 's1' id integer?

Answer (score 0):

instead of *index_integer=type(int(index_replace))* it should be *index_integer=int(index_replace)*